# how to send dataframe from shiny app to esquisser package?

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on a Shiny app that involves uploading two Excel files to create a new dataframe. I'm trying to integrate the 'esquisse' package to visualize this data. In my Shiny UI, I've set up an 'esquisse' tab using esquisse_ui, and in the server, I'm using esquisse_server to manage the 'esquisse' server.

I can see the variable names in the 'esquisse' tab, but when I attempt to create plots using 'esquisser', I encounter an error `"Error:` data`must be a data frame, or other object coercible by`fortify()`,`"  What could be the issue here?
Somewhere in the UI I use this :

```
tabPanel(
    title = "esquisse",
    esquisse_ui(
      id = "esquisse", 
      header = FALSE
      
    )
  )
```

as for my server:

```
  data_rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL) #

  observeEvent(recoded_data(), {
    data_rv$data <- recoded_data() 
  })

  
  esquisse_server(
    id = "esquisse",
    data_rv = data_rv
    
  )
```

about the recoded_data :

```
  data_file <- reactive({
  
  req(input$file1)
  
  df <- readxl::read_xlsx(input$file1$datapath, 1, col_names = TRUE)
  
  return(df)
  
})
  
  
  data_file2 <- reactive({
    
    req(input$file1)
    
    df2 <- readxl::read_xlsx(input$file2$datapath, 1, col_names = TRUE)
    
    return(df2)
    
  })
  
  
  
  recoded_data <- reactive({
    
    df <- data_file1()
    
    df2 <- data_file2()
    
    merged_data <- data_recoding(df, df2) #i simply replace numbers by their true values and return a dataframe 
    
    return(merged_data)
    
  })
```

Comment: What does `recoded_data()` return? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.